# Logging within a procedure's transaction

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, transaction, etl, log

I have an ETL process running inside a PostgreSQL 9.3 procedure on AWS RDS.  The procedure normally takes about ten minutes to run, but I'm having a rare issue where it takes several hours and never completes.

The procedure has a number of delete and insert statements, and I have them all running inside of a single transaction.  Running the same data by hand didn't reproduce the issue, so I'd like to do some basic logging to see which of the statements is causing a delay.  The process runs unattended, so I need a solution that I can check later.

What I can't figure out is how I can do logging from within a transaction.  Because this is on RDS, a simple `grep` of server logs isn't so simple, so I was hoping to just write a row to my own log table.  Is there an easy way of doing this?

Comment: That is what I want, however if the procedure is cancelled before a commit and everything is rolled back, that would also undo the logging as well.

Comment: You can try the `printf` style debugging as well by using something like `RAISE NOTICE 'I am here in my_procedure and processed % rows', v_num_rows;` in strategic places so you can see what's going on. It won't write to a table, but it should help with visibility.

Comment: If this were running on an unattended server, where would I go to see the printf messages?

Comment: They go into the logs, which on RDS, you can download from the Recent Events & Logs if you want to `grep` through them. And I forgot to mention you will need to enable `log_min_messages = notice` in your configuration too.